# How to submit website feedback to GitHub?

Tags: github, github-pages, github-api

I want to make a page on my website containing the information form for the bug they faced while using the website and web application.
Then I want to show those feedback to my private GitHub repository, so that I can keep track of all the bugs and work on fixing them.

Is there any GitHub API for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, https://github.com/tan-tan-kanarek/github-php-client this worked like a charm for me. In my scenario, I was working in phalcon framework and I used this API to submit issue to a private GitHub repository.
Authentication is pretty simple in this API .

Answer (score 2):

Using the GitHub API *(like suggested in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44150548/6884))* is a possible solution, but requires you to implement the UI by yourself, call the API with proper authentication etc. etc.

If you want a simpler solution with less work for you, you could point your users directly from your website to your GitHub issue tracker.

Unfortunately, GitHub doesn't support private repositories with public issues. Their official solution for this problem is to 
[create a second (public) repo and use this just to host the public issues](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-issues-only-repository/).

If changing your hosting provider is an option for you, you could migrate your project to [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/).
They offer [unlimited private repos for free if you have max. five users](https://bitbucket.org/product/pricing?tab=host-in-the-cloud), and **it's possible to have [a private repo with a public issue tracker](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/make-the-tracker-private-or-public-223216425.html).**

Quote from the last link:

> Users with administrative rights on a repository can set a Bitbucket
>   Cloud issue tracker as private or public.  When your tracker is
>   public, anyone can view, create, and comment on issues it contains. 
>   This includes people who land on the website but who do not have a
>   Bitbucket account. The  system asks these users to verify they are
>   people with a CAPTCHA.
>
> You can set your Bitbucket repository, wiki,
>   and issue tracker as private or public, independently of each other.
>   For example, you can hide your code from the world by setting your
>   repository as private, but let people see your documentation and
>   issues by marking your wiki and issue tracker as public. Or you could
>   set your repository and wiki as public but keep your issue tracker
>   private.  You can change any of these settings from private to public,
>   or public to private, at any time.

Comment: I was simply providing the direct answer to the question.. You provide a much better solution to the problem.+1 from me :)

Answer (score 1):

GitHub does have an API and one if its end-points is for creating bugs:

https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/